# Import google maps LatLngBounds

Tags: angular

How can import in typescript google.maps.LatLngBounds() I need this 'google.' whats is npm pack for this?

Comment: I would suggest next time to search google first https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/using-typescript

Answer (score 1):

You can install the package [`@types/google.maps`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google.maps), that makes the global variable `google` available, and then you can just use the type `window.google.maps.LatLngBounds` wherever you want.

Alternatively, you can install [`@googlemaps/types`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/types) which are Google-curated type definitions. They are auto-generated by Google themselves, but are relatively new and don't seem to have much [documentation](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-types) attached.